# WP7 - Clearing Isolated Storage for my application

Tags: windows-phone-7, storage, restart, swipe

I would like the users to be able to wipe out their isolated storage for my application and start over.  Is there a way to do this?  Is this suggested?  If so to both prior questions, what is the best way to do this?

**Update:**

After thinking about this question a little bit, I'm thinking I can probably look through my collection and do a remove operation...  So I guess that is one way.  Is there a more complete way?

Comment: Well there is the option to completely remove the isolated storage scope (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay840d1(v=VS.95).aspx) but I'm not sure you'd want to put that in the hands of your users? It would perhaps indicate the app isn't handling the cleanup of resources elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [Isolated Storage Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769544%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for Windows Phone? I think you would simply implement this through functionality in your app that gives user access to the relevant directory in the [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) scope and allows them to delete specific or in your case, all files. The [second link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) has examples of how to do this.

Comment: broken link to best practices

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [IsolatedStorageFile.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay840d1%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). It removes all the contents of the application's Isolated Storage.